# image working in index.blade.php but not show.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel to build a Events management system. Users can upload images to be displayed with their event. I have the img tag working on my `index.blade.php` and assumed I could use the same code on my `show.blade.php` page, it seems not.
I have the image stored in `public/images` and I am aware I should use storage for this but I am still learning basics so found this easier for now.

```
<img style="width:100%" src="images/{{$event->image}}">
```

Comment: put a `/` before your path. e.g. `src="/images/{{ $event->image }}`

Comment: try this one {{ URL::asset('images/'.$event->image) }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `asset()` method. The `asset()` method is used to include `CSS/JavaScript/images files`, you can use it as:

```
{{ URL::asset('images/'.$event->image) }}

<img style="width:100%" src="{{ URL::asset('images/'.$event->image) }}">
```

You can also use this function for `CSS and js`.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

For detail please see this article:

https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravels-url-to-vs-url-asset-fd427ed6f7ef

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall use that from now on

Comment: I am glad to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

As @Frank Ayyaz said you can use a backslash to solve this another Laravel-way is using [public_path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-public-path) method which returns the fully qualified path to the public directory. 
so you can do something like:

```
<img style="width:100%" src="{{ public_path('images/'.$event->image) }}">
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Not to use `URL::asset` but only asset method because sometime URL may cause Problem while showing the image...and use `dd()` function and check whether u are getting the path i.e `Public_path` , `storage_path()` or the custom like the image are stored in public directory..

You may use `asset()` method of Laravel and use any Prefix whatever you like..

#### Example:

**For static**

```
 <img src="{!! asset('assets/images/cams/cam-01.png') !!}" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="Card image cap">
```

**For Dynamic**

```
<img src="{!! $settings->aws_url.$performer->coverimage !!}" class="img-fluid" alt="Card image cap">
```

Answer (score 0):

when u use js or css or images u should use {{asset('path')}} to get the resource, it has noting to do with the blade u  use, but the resources path.